# how does the dictionary database get apended and saved for new entries after running my code_python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary

---

Below is an example code from automate the boring stuff from python book (by Al Swager),
in this code after I add a new birthday entry for 'Eve' and update the database, then my code stops. when I run this code again (the dictionary, i.e. Birthdays[] in this code is not updated to add data of 'Eve'), the data for Eve is not appearing. can you please explain how this dictionary can be updated ?

```
    birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}

while True:

    print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')

    name = input()

    if name == '':

        break



    if name in birthdays:

        print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)

    else:

        print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)

        print('What is their birthday?')

        bday = input()

        birthdays[name] = bday

        print('Birthday database updated.')
```

Comment: Please 1/ fix your code formatting, 2/ read [ask] and [mcve], 3/ edit your question accordingly.

Comment: code work without any problem, what is your problem exactly?